# Displaying images retrieved from mongodb in web browser?

Tags: php, html, image, mongodb

I am trying to retrieve an image from mongoDB and display it in web browser. But it is not working. Here is the code which I am using for insertion and retrieval

Code to upload:

```
<?php
//If you wanted to store the uploaded image in MongoDB, you could do the following in the script handling the form submission: 
if(isset($_REQUEST['formsubmit']))
{
    $m = new MongoClient();
    $coll = $m->test;
    $gridFS = $coll->getGridFS();
    $tag = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $gridFS->storeUpload('pic',array("tag"=>$tag));
    echo 'File Uploaded Successfully';
    $m->close();
}
?>
<!-- image and any file  uploaded  in mongodb -->
<html>
<head> Upload Image</head>
<body>
<!--The name of the uploaded file to store. This should correspond to the file field's name attribute in the HTML form. -->
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
        <label for="pic">Please upload a profile picture:</label>
        <input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" />
        <input type="submit" value="Register" name="formsubmit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code to retrieve image and display in browser:

```
<?php
//If you wanted to store the uploaded image in MongoDB, you could do the following in the script handling the form submission: 
    $m = new MongoClient();
    $coll = $m->test;
    $gridFS = $coll->getGridFS();
?>

<html>
<head>Displaying Image</head>
<body>
<?php
    header('content-type: image/jpg');
    echo '<img src=' . $gridFS->findOne(array("tag"=>"temp123"))->getBytes() .'>'. '</img>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Could anyone please help me out ??
Thank you

Comment: I see many problems like the header function after adding a Html body and img tags not working like tha but I have no idea what problem you are having because you don't actually say

Comment: @Sammaye My problem is the image is not getting displayed, instead a small icon is getting displayed.When I use inspect element corresponding to that icon it has php extension.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: No. I gave up on that.

Answer (score 0):

Really thankful for this wonderful opportunity to help you.
First of all..GridFS is using for saving files that more than 16mb size.You ain't mention on that question.
The below codes are for saving images less than 16mb.

```
***************** Image insertion**************

$target_dir = "upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["pic"]["name"]); //Image:<input type="file" id="pic" name="pic">
$tag = $_REQUEST['username'];
$m = new MongoClient();   
$db = $m->test;      //mongo db name
$collection = $db->storeUpload; //collection name

//-----------converting into mongobinary data----------------

$document = array( "user_name" => $tag,"image"=>new MongoBinData(file_get_contents($target_file)));

//-----------------------------------------------------------
if($collection->save($document)) // saving into collection
{
echo "One record successfully inserted";
}
else
{
echo "Insertion failed";
}

******************Image Retrieving******************

public function show()
{

$m=new MongoClient();
$db=$m->test;
$collection=$db->storeUpload;
$record = $collection->find();
foreach ($record as $data)
{
$imagebody = $data["image"]->bin;
$base64   = base64_encode($imagebody);
?>
<img src="data:png;base64,<?php echo $base64 ?>"/>
<?php
}
}
}
?>
```

Hope you will try this.Enjoy coding.Stay Blessed.